# fundamental redux concept- how to actions launch reducers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, reducers

to make things simple consider these two reducers(written in typescript):

```js
export type userActionTypes = 
    | Interface1
    | Interface2

const initialState1 =  {...//some state} //<--comment indicates some sort of values are present
const initialState2 =  {...//some state}

const reducer1 = (state = initialState1, action: userActionTypes){
    switch(action.type) {
        case action1.case1:
            return {...//some new state1}
        default: return state
    }
}

const reducer2 = (state = initialState2, action: userActionTypes){
    switch(action.type){
        case action2.case2:
            return {...//some new state1}
        default: return state
    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    mReducer1: reducer1,
    mReducer2: reducer2
})
```

now say somewhere we call the following in our code:

```js
newAction = {type: action2.type2, //some other values}
dispatch(newAction);
```

**my question is: ** How does react know which reducer to call? *I mean*, it doesn't pass the action to every reducer there is in the rootReducer, does it? I mean if that was the case, then all the default cases would be meaningless and all the cases in the `case` statements would have to be unique. That is not possible, is it?
How does react know which reducer to call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does react know which reducer to call? I mean, it doesn't pass the
> action to every reducer there is in the rootReducer, does it?

Trick question, redux actually calls ***all*** of your reducers.

Consider your root reducer:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  mReducer1: reducer1,
  mReducer2: reducer2
})
```

This creates a reducer function tree. When an action is dispatched to the store it calls the root reducer and passes the current `state` and the current `action`. The reducers in turn recursively call their nested combined reducers, passing `state` and `action` until they reach a leaf where you hit a reducer function and compute their next state. They either have a case to handle `action` or the return the default case which is simply their current state. The recursion goes back up, returning each next state slice piece, combined at each level until you arrive back at the root reducer which returns the entire next state object.

> I mean if that was the case, then all the default cases would be
> meaningless and all the cases in the case statements would have to be
> unique. That is not possible, is it?

Remember that each reducer function is operating on ***only*** its little slice of state, not the *entire* `state` object. The default case is there for the reducer to return its current state value since there is no work for it to do. All the reducer cases *within* a reducer function should be unique. If two actions trigger the same state update then they should be grouped

```
case "case1":
case "case13":
  // both cases apply the same update
```

Comment: the latter question in my post still remains, the `state` can be anything and the `action` can be anything, how does it uniquely identify the reducer? I mean if the action is passed to everyreducer, and say two reducers have the same `case` condition, then, it will invoke anyone of them?

Comment: yes. action dispatches to all the reducers and only reducers with that exact actions will act on it and others will discard it. @BumbleBee

Comment: @BumbleBee The beauty of redux reducer functions is they can respond/handle *any* action dispatched to the store. `state` and `action` are passed to every reducer function, and multiple reducers can handle the same action. They may do different things for *their* state slice, but they can do so from the same action. There's nothing really to do with identifying any specific reducer since they are all called.

Comment: @DrewReese , so the main point is this: `if two reducers have the same 'case' conditions, then they will both return a new State for their respective slice of state, that means all 'case' conditions int he entire reducer tree must be unique if we need to fire only one action` ?? Please confirm this

Comment: @Arka , PLEASE confirm my above comment

Comment: @BumbleBee I don't understand what you mean by "must be unique", what is "they" you refer to here? If you fire only one action and two reducers have a case to handle it, they both handle it. One reducer has nothing to with the other. What cases and how they are handled by any one reducer is completely independent of any other reducer's cases and logic. Global uniqueness among reducers cases isn't a requirement in redux if that is what you are driving at.

Comment: @DrewReese , I edited the 'they'. yes, exactly. One reducer has nothing to do with other. What I mean by "must be unique" is that if we want to only fire one reducer then in all the reducers we write, all the 'case' conditions in all the switch statements have a downside that they must be unique. I mean, I would was expecting each reducer to have something like scoping that much make a key unique for each reducer in turn indentifying the reducer to fire instead of firing all over the reducer tree with it. `I wonder if I am correct in understanding this`?

Comment: @BumbleBee Ah, I see... no, there's no control over calling any specific reducer function, they are simply all called and collectively compute the next state. It's really a rather simple way to manage state.

Comment: @BumbleBee no, you always dispatch only one action. there is no `dispatching same action multiple times for multiple reducers`. think of it like pdf/song download. you upload it only once you don't upload it for every other users. now who will download the pdf/song will depend on every user's requirement.

Comment: @Arka , I couldn't really connect the scenerio. But, What I've understood from drew's comments above, if there are two `case` statements with same value in different reducers, both their bodies are executed.`is this much true`?

Comment: @BumbleBee Not quite. The reducer function bodies (all of them) will always be executed when redux is handling a dispatched action. If two reducers have a case that handles the same dispatched action type then both cases' logic will be applied. I see maybe you meant the cases' bodies, and in this case (no pun intended), yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: I have explored the dispatch function and i found that calls the reducer function and the reducer function returns the current state. what i am not getting is that every body is saying that dispatch function calls the store and then store calls the reducers and return the new state. if it is the case then the dispatch function should have called the store not the reducer.

Comment: @HabibUrRehman `dispatch` is a function provided by Redux to dispatch actions *to the store*, the store then handles calling the reducer tree. `Dispatch` doesn't really call anything (other than action creators that return an action object). It certainly ***does not*** call any reducers directly.