# How can I simplify my reducer function or how long should a simple reducer function be?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a reducer function whose sole purpose it to toggle a style on and off.  This is a global style and this is why it is in my Redux store.

However, the code looks overly obtuse for such a simple toggle.

```
const Style = (state = {current: true}, action) => {
  if(action.type === "toggleAppStyle"){
    const newState = { ...state };
    newState.current = !state.current;
    return newState;
  }
  return state;
};
```

I recently realized that redux runs all reducer functions for each single action, which I find strange, so the returned state must equal the initial state if the action.type is not called for that particular reducer.

Here is the one place I use it:

```
// ... snip
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    Style: state.Style
  }
}
  
  // ... snip
  render() {
    return (
      <img className = 'icon_all' 
           id = {this.props.Style.current === true ? 'icon_10' : 'icon_90'} 
           onClick = {this.clickHandler} src='/images/favicon-optimized.svg'/>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the code looks overly obtuse for such a simple toggle.

Overly obtuse is a bit much, this is a pretty standard immutable update pattern, i.e. shallow copy into new object reference and update the necessary properties.

It can't get much simpler than what you've already got, but here is an example returning the new object directly.

```
const Style = (state = {current: true}, action) => {
  if (action.type === "toggleAppStyle") {
    return {
      ...state,
      current: !state.current,
    };
  }
  return state;
};
```

> I recently realized that redux runs all reducer functions for each
> single action, which I find strange, so the returned state must equal
> the initial state if the action.type is not called for that particular
> reducer.

Nothing strange here really. The reducer function either acts on the action and operates on the state, thus returning a ***new*** state reference and value, otherwise it simply returns the ***current*** state value. Other than the action part this is exactly how React reconciliation works. When you update state you are creating new object references or primitive values. This is what triggers rerenders.

Of course, if your objective is to be as short and succinct as possible, you could reduce the state slice to *just* the boolean value and use a ternary operator to return the toggled state or current state value. Adjust your redux selectors accordingly.

```
const Style = (state = true, action) => action.type === "toggleAppStyle"
  ? !state
  : state;
```

Comment: @howard Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67328798/8690857) shed some light on why/how Redux doesn't necessarily make assumptions about the exact shape of the reducer tree you compose/combine?

Comment: Yes ... I see now, I had a typo as well, thanks for that answer/reference.  Do you maintain Redux or similar?  You seem to have it down solid.

Comment: @howard Lol, that would be cool, but no, I mostly just learned from doing it the hard & wrong ways first and spending lots and lots of time reading documentation and source code. Work with it daily in the work I do though.

Comment: I had a idea/question.  In this case can I set the state to a value instead of an object ... i.e. `state = true` instead of `state = { current: true }` and then just toggle the value of state?

Comment: @howard Sure, I don't see why not! That's actually what I suggested at the end of my answer. 

Comment: I had a problem with Redux ( or the way I wrote it ) causing my all my components to Re-render when they don't need to, but it is fixed now.